# Confusing review regarding moderator flags

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I was about to report a post, at which point I noticed a message asking me to review why my last flag was rejected.  Naturally I reviewed it but I don't remember flagging this particular question, more so the overview does not match the question.

[image: My apparent report]

I do remember flagging a post recently for spam but it was certainly not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp/36289431#36289431).  I do not have a link to the question it was, but i can express it contained multi-byte characters flooding the page.

**Question**

Why does this overview highlight the voting as **-6** but when i view the question is states a **+145**. Is there any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: You flagged the now-deleted answer that has -6 votes, not the question itself.

Comment: O.o thanks, I have no idea what planet i'm on... how could I be so stupid.  I guess that then explains why my report was declined as the answer didn't exist when reviewed. herp derp me.

Comment: Here's the answer you flagged: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MeaVr.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you flag a post as spam, and it gets deleted, the flag gets marked helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks, not quite multibyte characters haha maybe a couple. But ok yes I did flag that ha

Comment: I'll refrain from my normal "asked about a question, linked to an answer" edit.

Comment: Actually, it was likely declined for not fitting Stack Overflow's description of "Spam". It's definitely, from the screenshot Alexander linked, _not an answer_ and most certainly _very low quality._

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Actually, that's not the case. (I have a pending spam flag on a deleted post on another site.) Since the spam flags feed the spam filter, it's better to make sure those flags are human validated.

Comment: @Kendra Was it flagged before or after it was deleted? Maybe it's only marked helpful if it gets deleted by spam flags, or resolved by moderator.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Before. Decently before. And yes, it's helpful if it's deleted by six spam flags, or one mod spam flag.

Comment: Martijn declined the spam flag before deleting the answer. Deleting it straight away would have validated the flag. (@Kendra, I suspect in your case the post wasn't deleted by a moderator.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You flagged an *answer*, not a question.

If you look under the link and to the right, you'll see "answered Mar 29..." meaning this flag was on an *answer* to that question.

Also note how the background of that link is red. This means the answer is deleted. Clicking the link takes you to the answer if you have the privilege to view deleted answers.  Otherwise the link will just take you to the question instead (or a 404 page if the question is deleted). The -6 would be the score on the deleted answer.

As a side note, thanks to a screenshot linked by Alexander O'Mara, the flag was likely declined for not fitting Stack Overflow's definition of spam. It didn't appear to be promoting anything, but instead appeared to be gibberish or an insanely poorly formatted post. One of the comments pointed out that it looked like a copy/paste of a search result page. This answer most definitely fit the "Not An Answer" and "Very Low Quality" flags, but not our definition of "Spam."

Comment: Links to deleted answers work for those with the 10k privilege right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes .

Comment: This doesn't explain though *why* the flag was declined. @MartijnPieters deleted it, but declined the spam flags. Perhaps he thought a VLQ flag would be more appropriate...

Comment: @user000001 The question didn't ask _why_ it was declined. The OP was more confused that they were linked to a question they didn't recall flagging as spam. However, it wouldn't hurt to add that, so I will.